# Setup HTTPs connection in SEEM Beacon Manager iOS Cordova SDK

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, seem-beacon-manager

I'am using https://github.com/glanzkinder/SEEM-Beacon-Manager-Cordova-SDK. All is working pretty fine by not using `SSL` via `HTTP`. I need to secure my connection via SLL but I can't figure out how to enable a "SSL"-Connection.

```
//SEEM API Configuration
SEEM.setApiPort(443);
SEEM.setApiUrl('my.example-domain.com');
SEEM.setAutoUuidFetch(true);

//try listen beacon
SEEM.startListeningToBeaconRegion(function(result) {
    console.log("Start Listening to Beacon Region successful: ");
    console.log("UUID: " + result[0]);
    console.log("major: " + result[1]);
    console.log("minor: " + result[2]);
}, function(result) {
    console.log("Start Listening to Beacon Region failed:");
    console.log(result);
}, 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX', null, null, true);
```

Here is my Error-Message:

> ```
> Start Listening to Beacon Region failed
> SSL-Connection error.
> ```

Does anyone know how to enable SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](https://github.com/glanzkinder/SEEM-Beacon-Manager-Cordova-SDK#setapisslenabled), you need to setup `SEEM.setApiSslEnabled(true);`. Just try this configuration:

```
//SEEM API Configuration
SEEM.setApiPort(443);
SEEM.setApiSslEnabled(true);
SEEM.setApiUrl('my.example-domain.com');
SEEM.setAutoUuidFetch(true);
```